How do we calculate flux and force in this electromagnetic circuit
Consider the following electromagnetic setup:
The measurements \$L_0\, B_0, L_1, B_1\$ are the mean lengths of each side. Let the direct current in the coil (with \$N\$ turns) be \$I\$ amps and the relative permeability of the core be \$\mu\$.
The flux in this setup is given by: \$\Phi=\mu NIa^2/(2L_0+2B_0+2L_1)\$ (Please correct me if I am wrong)
Now, the core is cut across the red lines before supplying current, with an extremely tiny gap b/w the upper and lower sections (say 1 millimeter).
Query 1: How do we calculate the total flux with this air separated sections?
Query 2: Assuming the lower part of the electromagnet is fixed and the upper part is allowed to move only in vertical direction, how do we calculate the magnitude of force in vertical and horizontal directions?
P.S. My background is not in electrical/electronics. And I am looking for an approximate formula (if an exact solution isn't possible).

Do you have any specific values for anything?

No. But we can assume length and dimensions are very large compared to the gap (which we can assume as 1 mm or even less if necessary). for example: sat 12 inches for each $L_0$ and $B_0$ or even larger.  I want to get a general formula (even for approximation) which I have searching quiet a lot, but haven't got anything. And we can assume a large current and an appropriate core like soft iron.

Air core is $\mu_r=1$ whereas laminated steel is 1000, so it will be very weak and soft iron is not Cold Rolled Grain Oriented Steel CRGOS

I am aware of the value of $\mu_r=1$ for air. But simply stating it will be very weak is the least helpful. Even permanent magnets pull at a distance, so weak is a relative term and not much help! I am looking for a formula for a numerical estimate. "and soft iron is not Cold Rolled Grain Oriented Steel CRGOS.." - OK.  But I never said it was, not I mentioned it. So I am unclear what you mean? I said assume any core. I am looking for a formula so that doesn't matter much.

@TheoryQ It cannot be that $\mu$ is the relative permeability. It must be that $\mu=\mu_{_0}\cdot \mu_r$, where $\mu_r$ is the relative permeability. I can't help any if we disagree on this point because if you maintain your position then your equation cannot make any physical sense. Perhaps review this answer by Andy aka? If you change your mind, I'll provide a way to answer your first question.
